# Absolute or Relative "templateUrls" for angular components

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner

Can someone please help me around this deadend of 1 vs 2?

1) Angular project as AoT in production.  This required my source code to be changed to have templateUrl and styleUrls that are **relative** to the component.ts file.

2) Angular karma as JiT for unit tests.  This required my source code to be changed to have templateUrl and styleUrls that are **absolute**, or the unit test will throw a 404 looking for the .html file.

I would like to avoid maintaining a relative AND an absolute path in the source code.

What are my options here?  What is the best practice?

(I'm USING WEBPACK with aot and Karma, NOT angular-cli)

Thanks!!

UPDATE: 
we're also going to explore converting to angular-cli, but this is a huge project and this is a blocker for us, if anyone knows the trick that angular-cli uses in order to pull this off. or even a work-around so we can get our unit tests back!

I need to know a trick to run Unit tests WITH AoT or at least ALONG SIDE AoT (in other words run aot production and jit unit tests with one set of templateUrls)

Thanks again!

PS..
This worked without AoT perfectly (with the absolute urls), but switching to AoT (with urls relative to the component file) has blocked us.

UPDATE 2:  (including all my config files)
if I have to create another config file to run tests with (which makes sense) but I'd like to know what 'magic' that test config needs in order to run JiT components, now that my urls are all relative.

webpack.config.js

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');
let aot = require('@ngtools/webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './Angular/main'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './dist/smartcommand-[name].min.js',
        // Lazy load modules by route & chunk
        chunkFilename: './dist/smartcommand-[name].chunk.[hash].min.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./'),
            path.resolve('./node_modules')
        ],
        alias: {
            'ng2-charts/charts/charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts/bundles/ng2-charts.umd.min.js'
            //'ng2-dragula': 'node_modules/ng2-dragula/bundles/ng2-dragula.umd.min.js'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // Ahead of Time Compilation
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack', exclude: [/\.(spec)\.ts$/] },
            // AoT requires all files to be loaded
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[path][name].[ext]' }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'main' }),
        // Ahead of Time Plugin
        new aot.AngularCompilerPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: path.resolve('./Angular/tsconfig.json'),
            entryModule: path.resolve('./Angular/_app.module#SmartCommandModule')
            // Use this setting to turn off AoT
            //,skipCodeGeneration: true
        }),
        // Only load the necessary locales for moment
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en|es/)
    ],
    // Minimize webpack console output
    stats: { assets: false, children: false }
};
```

karma.config.js

```
/* Karma Configuration */
'use strict';
module.exports = function (config) {
    let appBase = 'Angular/'; // transpiled app JS and map files

    config.set({
        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
            //'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',

            // preprocessors
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-sourcemap-loader', // show proper (un-bundled) stack traces
            'karma-coverage', // capture unit test code coverage
            'karma-trx-reporter' // report coverage in VSTS
        ],

        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        //browsers: ['Chrome'],
        browsers: ['Firefox'],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'karma-test-shim.js': ['webpack', 'coverage']
            // for debugging the tests
            //'karma-test-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            // polyfills
            'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

            'Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
            'Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js',

            'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
            'node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js',
            'node_modules/nipplejs/dist/nipplejs.js',

            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

            // rxJS
            { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

            // other dependencies
            { pattern: 'node_modules/applicationinsights-js/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/applicationinsights-js/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

            { pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-charts/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-charts/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
            'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js',

            { pattern: 'node_modules/primeng/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/ngx-slick/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },

            { pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-dragula/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-dragula/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

            // our SmartCommand bundle
            'dist/smartcommand-main.min.js',

            // our Karma tests
            { pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true },

            // paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

            // our assets (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },
            { pattern: 'Content/*.css', included: true, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'Content/*.css.map', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'Content/Images/**/*', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'Content/images/**/*', included: false, watched: false }
        ],

        // proxied base paths for loading assets
        proxies: {
            // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
            '/Angular/': '/base/Angular/',
            '/Content/': '/base/Content/'
        },

        // test results reporter to use
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage', 'trx'],

        // karma code coverage
        coverageReporter: {
            // specify a common output directory 
            dir: 'coverage',
            reporters: [
                // reporters not supporting the `file` property 
                { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
                { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' },
                // reporters supporting the `file` property, use `subdir` to directly 
                // output them in the `dir` directory 
                { type: 'cobertura', subdir: '.', file: 'cobertura.txt' },
                { type: 'lcovonly', subdir: '.', file: 'report-lcovonly.txt' },
                { type: 'teamcity', subdir: '.', file: 'teamcity.txt' },
                { type: 'text', subdir: '.', file: 'text.txt' },
                { type: 'text-summary', subdir: '.', file: 'text-summary.txt' }
            ]
        },

        // get code coverage in VSTS
        trxReporter: { outputFile: 'test-results.trx', shortTestName: false },

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,

        // continuous integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // concurrency level
        // how many browsers should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity,

        client: {
            captureConsole: false, // set to true if you need console output
            builtPaths: [appBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },

        // workaround for disconnects
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 5,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 50000
    });
};
```

karma test shim

```
// 'No stack trace' is usually best for app testing.
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0;
// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
//Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

// Import all .spec.js files in our Angular folder
let appContext = require.context('./Angular', true, /\.spec\.js$/);
appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

// Start the Test Environment
let testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
let browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');
testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Comment: Well, angular-cli uses webpack too, and works fine with relative paths. Use eject on a CLI project and see how they did that? Or use the CLI.

Comment: i did try the ng eject trick quickly once and didn't see anything useful in the webpack.config.js.  that is good to know that CLI works. Thanks!! took your advice tried again to ng eject on a CLI project WITH child components. i see they are starting all urls with './'  but that didnt' seem to help much.  also took their parameters they pass into the AoTplugin but no help either.  maybe it's in here, but i just dont know what i'm looking for

Comment: there has to be some magic somewhere in this CLI project that i can copy over into my webpack project..  i hope..  in case I cannot find anything do you know of any references for converting from webpack to cli?  thanks again!

Comment: I'd just start over with a brand new cli project, and move every file where the CLI expects them to be. I'm no webpack expert at all. That's why I leave that to the CLI and the google experts writing the build for me.

Comment: ok thanks, i may resort to that if i dont get an answer, thank you!!

Comment: @Jesse What are you using to load code in the browser in your unit tests? SystemJS?

Comment: @Louis, webpack, and karma.config.js

Comment: @Louis, we also have a karma-test-shim.js that i can share if think that would help.  this worked without AoT perfectly with the absolute urls, but switching to AoT and relative urls has blocked us.

Comment: @Jesse I asked because it is often the case that people have a development build for testing which use JiT and SystemJS, and a production build which uses AoT compilation and Webpack. If you use Webpack for testing and production, then the relative paths should work in both cases, unless you made a mistake in the Webpack configuration you use for testing. I'm not sure whether `karma-test-shim.js` would be useful. (Is it what most Karma tutorials call `test-main.js`?) However, I'm inclined to think you won't get a precise answer without showing your Webpack configurations.

Comment: thank you that's the most help i've got all week!  i'll share the files!  that does give me a lot to go on.  i'd like to keep it all webpack. i do NOT have a separate webpack config for dev and testing.  so it sounds like that might be my problem?  do you have a sample of a 'test' webpack config so i can see if there is a relative url trick in there i can steal?  i'll add my dev config and my karma shim.  thank you!

Comment: @Jesse I see the Webpack configuration you posted. What puzzles me is if this configuration is used for the testing build, then how do you get a JiT out of it? When I look at that configuration, I see AoT, and *only* AoT. I see `skipCodeGeneration` but it is commented out. I don't have a Webpack configuration I use for testing. For testing I follow the practices I've most often seen in Angular documentation/tutorials/etc: I use SystemJS to load my code in Karma. There's a JiT build that happens prior to running Karma but it does not involve Webpack at all. I use Webpack only for the AoT build.

Comment: @Louis via the karma.config and the karma.test-shim.  i'll share those also..   i agree it's probably a configuration issue on my end (i hope) but i guess i'm still confused if i do create an entirely new systemjs config, or an entirely new webpack.config for testing purposes, I'm 99% sure I'll still be missing the same 'magic'.  and of course that magic is:  how in the world can i JiT components if the urls are all relative.

Comment: there has to be some magic or somethign i'm not understanding.  i can configure it in all ways and get it working, but now that i've changed the SOURCE code, it seems that JiT doesn't work anymore.  i have seen webpack test files so i think it should be possible with webpack.  in fact, i dont have time to go back to systemjs, but in theory, what about systemjs would allow the components to find their templates??  everything i try to do looks in the site's root for ALL component templates (since all the urls are relative now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem I'm seeing. You are in fact using two different Webpack configurations. Obviously, there's your `webpack.config.js` which is set for AoT.

However, you are using another, different, configuration when you run Karma. The `karma-webpack` plugin provides the Webpack instance that runs in the Karma process with its own configuration. Unless you yourself write code in your `karma.config.js` to read `webpack.config.js`, then Karma will completely ignore that file. So effectively, when you are running Karma, you are running with a different Webpack configuration. The problem is that currently your configuration is empty, which means that Angular is processing `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` "raw", and you get the results you are getting.

You need to setup Webpack with a loader that will process the `templateUrl` and `stylesUrls` to have Webpack handle them. I would use [`angular2-template-loader`](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader) for this.

Looking at your configuration, it seems that by the time Karma sees your files, they've all been transpiled to JavaScript. Normally, `angular2-template-loader` is used on TypeScript files, but since it does its job using regular expressions, it also works on JavaScript files.

I'd expect adding Webpack configuration with `angular2-template-loader` to your `karma.config.js` should work, and adjust for needs specific to your project:

```
webpack: {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['angular2-template-loader'],
        // exclude: [...] You may want to exclude your test files here
        // to save some build time.
      },
      // etc. with raw-loader, html-loader and file-loader as needed.              
    ]},  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I'll try this as soon as I can!!

Comment: You are the man!!!  it is adding /base/ in front of all the paths (which I'm sure I can take care of)  but the rest of the path is correct based on the component instead of all being at the site's root!!!   Thank you so much!!  That's EXACTLY what I was looking for, I have been stuck on that for like a week!!  I'd buy you a drink if i could!